# Putting <br> in a horizontal <ul> breaks it?

Tags: html, css, layout

This is the code for a horizontal `<ul>` that I'm using:

```
.list ul{
    width: 100%;
}

.list li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Using this, if I do this:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
       <img src="myImg.png" />
       <span class="edit"></span>
       <span class="delete"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then it all works, however if I put a `<br>` between the image and the edit/delete buttons, e.g:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>
       <img src="myImg.png" />
       <br />
       <span class="edit"></span>
       <span class="delete"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then the list breaks, and I get the images in a vertical list instead of horizontal. Screenshot when its working:

[image: Working]

Screenshot of when its not working:

[image: Not working]

Any ideas?

Comment: But that `br` isn't between the image and the buttons. It's outside the `li`.

Comment: you shouldn't put a <br> element in a <ul> element

Comment: Its in the li in my actual code, I made a typo putting it in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the

`display: inline`

with

`float: left`

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cajy7/)

Comment: Thanks, this solves the css issue, but then it makes my page look like this: http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/i/248671-517201232005am.png

Comment: I.e its not pushing down the border of its container div. It looks super imposed.

Comment: Have updated my [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Cajy7/1/)  

Add the .clearfix css and add the clearfix class to your <ul>

Comment: Thanks! It works great now. Can you explain what the issue was so it can be avoided in future?

Comment: I'm not the best at explaining these kinds of things but I'll give it a try... the first problem was because your `li`'s were display: inline. This means the `br`'s were causing line breaks but obviously not as you intended (each subsequent `li` ending up on the new line too). Floating the `li`'s gives the same effect you were after but leaves the `li`'s as display:block so the `br` works as you expect. The second issue was caused because we floated all of the `ul`'s children, this caused the `ul` to lose it's layout and to fix this we needed to apply the 'clearfix'.

Comment: not sure i understand the last part about the clearfix, but thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's kind of tricky to explain. You should find plenty of articles about it if you google 'clearfix css' :)

Comment: it's not the best answer, FLOAT is not a good thing. for example, you cannot add border-bottom properly. inline-block is a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use: `display:inline-block` on your `li` element which then allows all other markup to function correctly, both in and out of your list.

[inline-block: The element is placed as an inline element (on the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdQEy/2) showing an example.

The above jsfiddle is now edited to support older IE7 to work alongside modern browsers. The order of the .css for `display` is important. To throw in support for IE6, then additonal `_height: 30px;` where `30` is your required height needs to be added. But [IE6 browser use](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp) is less than 1%.

Comment: This is a good option if you don't need to worry about versions of IE < 8

Comment: Updated fiddle to include support for older browsers, but typically using a separate CSS file is used to support IE7 these days.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use for .list li { float:left; } instead { display:inline; } and will work.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the css issue, but then it makes my page look like this: http://www.webpagescreenshot.info/i/248671-517201232005am.png I.e its not pushing down the border of its container div. It looks super imposed.